# merge the Boxes of interest of a data frame in a same column

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm a beginner in R. For my internship I need to make a new column of the unique non-NA value of each row of my a dataframe. The thing is this value is not always on the same column.

I'm editing my post. Here is my code

```
wd<-getwd()
datapath<-paste0(wd,"/data/HSgeneAges.tab")
feat<-read.table(datapath,sep='\t',header = TRUE)
feat<-data.frame(feat[,c(2,3,4,9)])
#creating a dataframe of 18 columns 
#with colnames to be each unique value of column 4 of  feat dataframe
geneage<-data.frame(matrix(ncol=18,nrow=0))
nomcol<-unique(feat[,4])
colnames(geneage)<-nomcol

for (i in 1:length(feat[,4])){  # as many rows as in feat
  for (j in 1:length(nomcol)){  # length is 18 ( number of columns of geneage)
    if (feat[i,4]==nomcol[j]){
      geneage[i,j]<-j
    }
  }
}
#binding geneage and feat on commons columns 
#and removing that column than make a file out of it
geneage<-cbind(feat,geneage)
geneage<-geneage[,-4]
datapath<-paste0(wd,"/data/p.txt")
write.table(geneage,datapath)
```

[Here is what the code produces so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OtP9.png) ( I can't show you all the row (21) as there are too many)

And here is what I'dlike to have ( an example on the first 11 rows)

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Chromosome = c("X", "X", "20", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "6", "6", "6", "1"), Start = c(99883667L, 99839799L, 49551404L, 
169818772L, 169631245L, 27938575L, 196621008L, 143815948L, 53362139L, 
41040684L, 24683489L), End = c(99894988L, 99854882L, 49575092L, 
169863408L, 169823221L, 27961788L, 196716634L, 143832827L, 53481768L, 
41067715L, 24743424L), geneage = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 
2, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 11L))
```

I hope to be clearer now.

By the way if somenone knows of to avoid the loops I ager to know how!
Alexis.

Comment: please share a reproducible sample of your data set with `dput(head(data))` so that we can use it to help you more efficiently.

Comment: right here is a sample produce byt dput(head(mydata)) structure(c("function (x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE) ", "{", 
"    if (missing(ncp)) ", "        .Call(C_df, x, df1, df2, log)", 
"    else .Call(C_dnf, x, df1, df2, ncp, log)", "}"), .Dim = c(6L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), ""), class = "noquote")

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).